# Можно ли закрыть прямоугольник кругом?

Tags: java, геометрия

Имеется прямоугольное отверстие размерами a и b, определить, можно ли его полностью закрыть круглой картонкой радиусом r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получается примерно следующая проверка:

```
if (r * r >= (a * a + b * b) / 4)
    System.out.println("Можно");
else
    System.out.println("Нельзя");
```

Comment: разве не `2 * r >= Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b) `? почему произведение радиусов и сумму квадратов делим на 4 , я что то пропустил на геометрии?

Comment: @pavloff а вы возведите обе части своего неравенства в квадрат и разделите на 4 - получите точно такое же неравенство, как у меня :)
я руководствовался теоремой Пифагора: радиус r - гипотенуза, a/2 и b/2 - катеты. по теореме Пифагора квадрат гипотенузы равен сумме квадратов катетов.

Comment: @pavloff ваша проверка лучше хотя бы потому, что меньше вероятность переполнения

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Ну зато там есть медленное вычисление корня. А в каком случае переполнение даст неправильный результат для первой формулы, и правильный для второй?

Answer (score 3):

Диагональ прямоугольника является диаметром описанной окружности. Потому берём Теорему Пифагора и делаем простую проверку. А результаты работы вашей программы можете проверить [тут](https://www.fxyz.ru/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B/%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%83%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/) например.